# Overriding an abstract Enum property in C#

Tags: c#, properties, enums, abstract

I have a base class and an enum type defined in a different class.  The base class has an abstract System.Enum property that I would like to implement using my custom enum type, however I keep getting an error saying my derived property "must be type System.Enum to match overridden member."

My enum type looks like this:

```
public static class EnumClass
{
    public enum MyEnum {
        option1,
        option2
    };
}
```

My base class looks like this:

```
public abstract class BaseClass 
{
    public abstract Enum Specification { get; set; }
}
```

And my derived class looks like this:

```
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass 
{
    private EnumClass.MyEnum mSpecification;

    public override EnumClass.MyEnum Specification
    {
         get { return mSpecification; }
         set { mSpecification = value; }
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me why my enum isn't a System.Enum type? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are changing the property type in the override, no can do. Must match exactly.

Comment: Be grateful. Imagine the over-engineered nightmares you could write with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `BaseClass` gives a "promise" that all of its subclasses will have the property `Specification` of type `System.Enum`. That means, if I have any object `BaseClass b = ...`, I can assign to its `Specification` with `b.Specification = enumValue` where `enumValue` is **any** `System.Enum`.

Now, if you derive in `DerivedClass`, I can no longer assign **any** `System.Enum` to `EnumClass.MyEnum Specification`, but only values of type `EnumClass.MyEnum`. This is why this property does not satisfy the contracts of its base class.

Therefore, the compiler will tell you that this implementation violates the inheritance from the abstract base class and you have to use the same property type in the derived class as well.

For better understanding, split the property into two methods:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public abstract System.Enum GetSpecification();
    public abstract void SetSpecification(System.Enum value);
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    private EnumClass.MyEnum specification;
    public override EnumClass.MyEnum GetSpecification()
    {
        return specification;
    }
    public override void SetSpecification(EnumClass.MyEnum value)
    {
        specification = value;
    }
}
```

Obviously, `BaseClass.SetSpecification` cannot be overridden by `DerivedClass.SetSpecification` because the parameter type `EnumClass.MyEnum` is a **subclass** of `System.Enum`.

If you want to allow a specific type of enum for every subclass, you can use generics for that:

```
public abstract class BaseClass<T> where T : struct, IConvertible // almost only enums
{
    public abstract T Specification { get; set; }
}
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass<EnumClass.MyEnum>
{
    public EnumClass.MyEnum Specification { get; set; }
}
```

Unfortunately, `where T : enum` is not possible so there is still the possibility of passing other `IConvertible` `struct`s to the generic type parameter.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  I want to make sure that any derived classes have a Specification property, but they all have their own enums of different specifications.  There must be a better way to go about this?

Comment: @KevinMarsh: You can use generics for that. I will update my answer